# C# 4 - DataGridView with proper ProgressBar control

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview, custom-cell

I need to display a progress bar in a DataGridView.

I've searched around and I've found [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646920/populating-a-datagridview-with-text-and-progressbars) ([many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571079/progressbar-control-in-datagrid-in-c), [many](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2/), [...](http://www.onteorasoftware.net/post/DatagridView-ProgressBar-Column.aspx)) implementations that basically render a progress bar by *drawing* it into the cell.

Isn't there a way to use a System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar directly in a DataGridView cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without drawing it into the cell.

However, you can check out DevExpress's DataGrid. It allows you to use a ProgressBar or any other control in any cell. I use it and found that is is much easier to use and customize.

Here's the link : http://devexpress.com/Products/Index/Grids.xml

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure about forking out that much extra just to get the functionality. Do you know why it's not possible without drawing it into the cell?

Comment: I wonder how DataGridView does it to render a Checbox column.. I essentially want the same but with a Progressbar instead of the checkbox

Comment: @Ben. I understand completely. It is a lot of money, but is mucho worth it. The data grid allows you to choose a checkbox, but what it's really doing behind the scenes is exactly what you'll have to do in order to get a progressbar in there. The reason you have to do is is simply because Microsoft hasn't abstracted that for you as they did with the checkbox.